# Where clause in VBA statement

Tags: sql, vba

I am having a problem with VBA,

I have the following lines 
VID & TXTapp are both fields filled in on a form and this statment should run after TXTApp is updated.

```
sSQL = "SELECT VID, App_Date, App_Time"
sSQL = sSQL & " FROM QRY_subform"
sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE VID = " & Me.VID & "AND App_Date = #" & Me.TXTApp & "#"
Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

but it doesn't seem to be passing the date field to the query, not sure what is wrong with it.
Any help would be greatfully excepted as this is driving me mad.

Comment: You are potentially open to SQL injection, which might be a large concern.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse is correct. You must sanitise your data before putting them in a SQL. In any case, why not do a `Debug.Print sSQL` to see what the SQL you are running looks like? Come on! Use your loaf!

Comment: @mark, I am new to VBA so i am learning as i go along.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before `AND` in the third line otherwise you may be getting a syntax error

`sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE VID = " & Me.VID & " AND App_Date = #" & Me.TXTApp & "#"`
not
`sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE VID = " & Me.VID & "AND App_Date = #" & Me.TXTApp & "#"`

You could debug this for yourself by adding the line `Debug.Print sSQL` after you have built your query, or using a Watch on `sSQL` and eyeballing the String you have built.

Comment: Hi thanks for that but it still doesn't seem to be filtering on the date field although it is passing it

Comment: What does `sSQL` look like when you do `Debug.Print` after this change?

Comment: @ JustineJDaviesThanks for your help, it is now passing the correct data, i have never tried to write this type of code in VBA so didn't realise how the debug system works.